# How to batch unpack p7s/p7m files

Tags: pkcs#7

I have thousands of files p7s/p7m files and I would like to get the original files.
Is there an solution to unpack all of them at once?

I found this: https://www.example-code.com/csharp/crypt_extract_from_p7m.asp
I used for a couple of days, but after a while, it didn't work anymore.

There are a couple of apps which unpack these files individually, but I would like a batch solution.

Any suggestions? (Could maybe openssl help me here?)

Comment: Consider writing a small script that for each file prints out the command to convert it.  Then collect those commands in another script and run that.

Comment: Could tell the line wich I would unpack the p7s file? I've tried "openssl.exe smime -verify -in file.P7M -noverify -inform DEM -out test.txt" , but my pdf file is empty.

Comment: I don't know how to do your particular problem, but that is how I would approach "Do X for all files in folder Y".  I would suggest you open another question on "How do I decrypt a p7s file  from the command line"